# Apache Rewrite Rule x?y/z into x/w/z .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite rule in htaccess.
I can't understand how to rewrite this url:

> https://example.com/forumdisplay.php?125-Wiki-Encyclopedia/page2&order=desc

into this:

> https://example.com/wikipedia/page2&order=desc

The part of the link - `"page2&order=desc"` in this link is changeable, it can be `"page3"`, `"page10&order=desc"` etc.

I am trying to redirect link in .htacess. 
Smth like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f=125&page=(\d+)&order=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^forumdisplay.php wikipedia?page=%1&order=%2 [R=301,L]
```

But in question is `/page` instead of `&page` .

Comment: The target URL you wrote does not make sense: `https://example.com/wikipedia/page2&order=desc`... What is the `&` doing in that URL?

Answer (score 0):

You have many issues at your rules like  `f=125` which is `125` in menthioned URLs.

Try This :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^125\-Wiki\-Encyclopedia\/page(\d+)&order=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^forumdisplay.php  wikipedia/page=%1&order=%2? [R=301,L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache and then test